# How to formulize some group is cyclic in first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

How should o formulize a group  is cyclic?
To write this i need to use the set of natural numbers but the universe is just the set of elements of the group.
If the group is (Z,+) i can use the positive part of Z to take needed n but just if < is in language... If not i don't know what to do...

Comment: There is no first-order formula in the language of groups expressing that a group is cyclic. How much of model theory do you know?

Comment: I'm very new in model theory...  And try ing to undrstad basics...

Comment: You say there is no firs order formula for cyclic groups because the ultra product of cyclic groups is not cyclic?

Comment: This is a way of seeing it. Another way to see it is that there is an infinite cyclic group, but no uncountable cyclic group

Comment: Exactly. The ultraproducts of cyclic groups is not cyclic, but this require knowing ultraproducts. Also, there are no uncountable cyclic groups, so we can obtain a contradiction using Lowenheim-Skolem theorem. I just wrote a solution using compactness and completeness, which are "very in the basics" of model theory.

Comment: The best you can do is an infinitely long "first order sentence" such as $$\exists x\forall y(y=1\lor y=x\lor y=x^{-1}\lor y=x^2\lor y=x^{-2}\lor y=x^3\lor\cdots)$$

Comment: A subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic, but the union of a chain of cyclic groups is not necessarily cyclic. (For example, the additive group of the rational numbers is the union of a chain of cyclic groups.) A first order sentence which is preserved by substructures is equivalent to a universal sentence, and is therefore also preserved by unions of chains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can show that "being cyclic" is not first-order expressible, that is,

**Proposition:**

> **Proposition:** There is no first-order sentence $\varphi$ in the language of groups $L=\{+\}$ such that $G\models \varphi$ if and only if $G$ is cyclic.

*Proof:* Suppose $\varphi$ is such sentence. For every $n\geq 1$, let $\phi_n$ be the sentence $$\displaystyle{\phi_n:=\exists x_1,\ldots,x_n\left(\bigwedge_{1\leq i<j\leq n}x_i\neq x_j\right),}$$ expressing the existence of at least $n$ distinct elements. Consider the set of sentences

$$\Gamma:=\{\sigma_{ab-gr},\varphi, \forall x \exists y (y+y=x)\}\cup\{\phi_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ where $\sigma_{ab-gr}$ is a sentence expressing that $(G,+)$ is an abelian group. We show now that $\Gamma$ is finitely consistent.

Let $\Gamma_0$ be a finite subset of $\Gamma$. Then, $\Gamma_0$ uses finitely many sentences of the form $\phi_n$, and by taking an odd prime $p>\max\{n:\phi_n\in \Gamma_0\}$ we have $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\models \Gamma_0$, as it is a cyclic group, every element "can be divided by 2" and has more than $n$ elements for every $n$ with $\phi_n\in \Gamma_0$.

Therefore, by compactness theorem, $\Gamma$ is consistent, and by completeness theorem, it must have a model $(M,+)$.

However, if $(M,+)\models \Gamma$, then $(M,+)$ is an infinite cyclic group, and since the only infinite cyclic group (up to isomorphism) is $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ we would have $(\mathbb{Z},+)\models \forall x \exists y (y+y=x)$, a contradiction as $x=1$ is not "divisible by $2$".