# How to distinguish two groups $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ , $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z},+)$ using first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> How can I distinguish two groups $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z},+)$ in first order logic?

---

The first one is cyclic and the second one is not but I can't find any thing in first order to prove they are not the same.

Comment: You just posted this a very similar question before. I hope you do not want us just to do you homework. Have you tried anything? 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2483323/how-to-formulize-some-group-is-cyclic-in-first-order-logic,

Comment: A hint for this one -  try to think about parity properties: in $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ every element is either even (=divisible by 2) or odd (=not divisible by 2). What about $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Not a home work... Iam not even student now!!! I'm studying logic to make sure if i like it and want to study logic from next year! Thanx i think this will wok

Comment: Expanding on Dario's comment: If we define odd to mean not even then of course it's true that everything is  either even or odd in both groups. But there's another way to define "odd" that's valid in one but not the other...

Comment: The appropriate phrasing would be that the two structures in question are not elementarily equivalent.

Comment: Is it external to first-order logic to point out that the signatures are not the same?  I mean you aren't quantifying over anything to say that Z×Z does not equal Z.

Comment: Doesn't the first order theory of a structure include it's signature?  Or does it?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Both groups (indeed all groups) have the same signature.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I don't know what you're talking about. The symbol "$\mathbb Z$" is not used in the theory of the structure $(\mathbb Z, +)$.

Comment: First-order group theory would be better.  Equality isn't actually in first-order logic (at least so long as first-order logic means predicate calculus). Equality exists in the extension of first-order logic with equality, and you need that to formulate group theoretic axioms.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Oh. I just noticed you pointing out that $\mathbb Z\ne\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$. Asking to "distinguish" the two is asking how to show that they're not _isomorphic_...

Comment: I removed all comments that deal with open/close and the edits. If further discussion about this is needed please use the chat attached to the answer. (I did not want to create a second room for the same thread.) If ever any comments should be needed for reference, let me know.

Comment: The chat mentioned by @quid may be found [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67484/discussion-on-answer-by-david-c-ullrich-how-to-distinguish-two-groups-mathbb).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might have been better to ask for a proof in the first-order theory of groups, instead of "in first-order logic", since after all ZF is a first-order theory. Not to be pedantic, but it seems this *did* lead to some confusion. Anyway:

Consider the sentence $\exists k \forall x \exists y (x=y+y\lor x=y+y+k)$.

Or, to say the same thing more colorfully: Note that "the subgroup of even elements has index $2$" is definable in the first-order theory of abelian groups.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67484/discussion-on-answer-by-david-c-ullrich-how-to-distinguish-two-groups-mathbb).